# setText and OnClickListener does not work

Tags: android, android-button

I am new in Android so i am facing many problems. I am to do a simple program which can take a value from edittext and print it in the textview by clicking on a button. Here is my code:
[image]

The program says, unfortunately it's stopped working. But when ever i delete last few lines from setOnClickListener it works fine. also i have tested it only by setText. it also is not working. thanks.
Logcat:
[image]

XML:
[image]

Comment: post you logcat here..

Comment: in what cases will `savedInstanceState` be null?

Comment: i dont know. it's autogenerated.

Comment: could you share xml code snippet of button & textview?

Comment: try this: tv.setText("pressed");

Comment: i have tried it first. it wont work..

Comment: ima solve it for ya, but one question is your edittext and buttons in the activity or fragment..

Comment: share your full code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should be in `PlaceHolderFragment`, like following..

```
public class PlaceHolderFragment extends Fragment {
    private EditText et;
    private Button b;
    private TextView tv;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
            false);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        et=(EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.EditText1);
        b = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.Button1);
        tv = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        b.setOnClicklistener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0){
                tv.setText("Pressed");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And remove these codes from `onCreate()`

```
et=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText1);
b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button1);
tv = (Button) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
b.setOnClicklistener(new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0){
        tv.setText("Pressed");
    }
});
```

Try this...

**Update**

1. activity_main.xml

[image]

2. fragment_main.xml

[image]

3. MainActivity.java

```
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        private EditText et;
        private Button b;
        private TextView tv;

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                    false);
            return rootView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

            et = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            b = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.button1);
            tv = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    tv.setText("Pressed");
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: it will work same as we put the code on onCreate..

Comment: How it will work same as the code on onCreate.. do you have the same controls in activity main, if you have means you doing in wrong way.. learn android first, then do code.

Comment: Your controls should be fragment_main.

Comment: it cant find getview

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63833/discussion-between-gunaseelan-and-somnath-kayal).

Answer (score 0):

I think the xml you shared is `fragment_main` not `activity_main`. Make sure you are inflating the right xml and refer to it's control only... The `NULL Pointer Exception` is being generated due to that only.

As per your code, *the textview , edittext and button must reside in `activity_main.xml` only*

```
 et=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText1);
 b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button1);
 tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
```

Confirm it.

If the control are in frgament_main, you need to use this code :

```
public class PlaceHolderFragment extends Fragment {
    private EditText et;
    private Button b;
    private TextView tv;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
            false);

        et=(EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.EditText1);
        b = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.Button1);
        tv = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        b.setOnClicklistener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0){
                tv.setText("Pressed");
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }

}
```